# Как постить картинки с сайта в популярные соцсети?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как постить картинки с сайта в популярные соцсети?
Есть ли готовые библиотеки которые реализуют постинг в vkontakte, facebook, twitter, odnoklassniki и тд.?

Comment: вам нужны api соц сетей для таких штук

Comment: https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes-next  нашел вот такую, но почему то не работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если коротко то в каждой социальной сети есть свое `API` которое позволяет с ней взаимодействовать.

- facebook - [API Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api)
- vk - [Open API](https://vk.com/dev/openapi)
- twitter - [REST APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

У каждого API свои особенности и универсального инструмента нет. Можно попытаться для каждого из этих API написать свою обертку, можно пользоваться уже написанными другими разработчиками (смотрим [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=facebook%20api%20&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)).

Если бы мне нужно было использовать в своем приложении несколько социальных сетей, я бы реализовал один класс-интерфейс общего взаимодействия с соц. сетями, а уже в нем использовал классы-реализаторы каждого необходимого API. При таком подходе для всего приложения у вас допустим есть только метод `socialSharer.postPicture()` и уже в этом `postPicture()` вы уже реализуете свои механизмы. Таким образом ваше приложение понятия не имеет каким образом и в какие соц. чаты вы постите картинки, плюс вы можете подключать сколько угодно реализаций социальных сетей так как работа с ними происходит в одном месте.